# draw a figure showing inequality relation

Tags: draw

I want to draw a figure in latex like this:
[image]

Would any one give me some tips? Thanks!

Comment: Try IPE. You can do this in tikz or asymptote. But IPE is the easiest because it is WYSIWYG. You get a pdf, png or jpg output that you can insert in latex. See here: http://ipe.otfried.org

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please read https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=-2pt,
every arrow/.append style={dash}]
A&\le &B&\le &C&\le &D\arrow{dlll}[description]{\le}\\
&&&E\arrow{ulll}[description]{\le}\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:* and if you want curved lines, just add `bend left=25` to the arrow style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=-2pt,
        every arrow/.append style={dash, bend left=25}]
        A&\le &B&\le &C&\le &D\arrow{dlll}[description]{\le}\\
        &&&E\arrow{ulll}[description]{\le}\\
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

To get this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly different circular approach:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (180:1cm) node {\( A \)}
  -- (120:1cm) node {\( B \)} node[sloped,pos=.5] {\( \leqslant \)}
  -- (60:1cm) node {\( C \)} node[sloped,pos=.5] {\( \leqslant \)}
  -- (0:1cm) node {\( D \)} node[sloped,pos=.5] {\( \leqslant \)}
  -- (-90:.7cm) node {\( E \)}  node[sloped,pos=.5] {\( \leqslant \)}
  -- cycle  node[sloped,pos=.5] {\( \leqslant \)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Haha, thanks for the fun circular approach. It is a nice example for presenting a circular relation :-)

Answer (score 2):

A `pstricks` solution, using an ordinary displaymath environment and a `psmatrix`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % for pdflatex compilation

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=4ex]
        \rnode{A}{A} ≤ B \Rnode{le}{{} ≤ {}} C ≤ \rnode{D}{D} \\
        [name=E] E
        \psset{nodesep=0.3em, nrot=:U, linewidth=0.5pt, linecolor=Tomato, framesep=1pt}
        \nccurve[angleA=-80, angleB=160]{A}{E}\ncput*{ ≤ }
        \nccurve[angleA=20, angleB=-110]{E}{D}\ncput*{ ≤ }
    \end{psmatrix} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Bernard, thanks! The inequalities between A, E, and D look very cool.

Comment: @PepperM: If you decide to use this solution  with pdflatex, don't forget to add to the compiler the switch `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeXLive, MacTeX).

Comment: Bernard, thanks for your help. I appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

for fun, far more complicated than [CarLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/101651/carlatex) answer :-) :

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, chains,
                positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm and 0mm,
  start chain = A going right,
  every node/.style = {inner sep=1mm, font=\large, on chain},
                        ]
% equation
\node   {$A$};      % A-1
\node   {$\leq$};
\node   {B};
\node   {$\leq$};   % A-4
\node   {$C$};
\node   {$\leq$};
\node   {$D$};      % A-7
%
\node[below=of $(A-2.south)!0.5!(A-3.south)$] {$\leq$}; % A-8
\node[below=of A-4] {$E$};                              % A-9
\node[below=of $(A-5.south)!0.5!(A-6.south)$] {$\leq$}; % A-10
% lines
\draw[thick, rounded corners, red]  
    (A-7) |- (A-10) (A-10) -- (A-9) (A-9) -- (A-8)  (A-8) -| (A-1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Zarko, thanks for the fun solution. I have earned a lot from you guys !

Answer (score 1):

I would use TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.base), inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \node (A) {$A$};
    \node (leq) [base right=0pt of A] {${}\leq B \leq C \leq {}$};
    \node (D) [base right=0pt of leq] {$D$};
    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={fill=white, inner sep=2pt}]
        \draw[draw=red, bend right=60, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt] (A.south) to
            node [pos=.25] {$\leq$}
            node [pos=.50] {$E$}
            node [pos=.75] {$\leq$}
        (D.south);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can change the size of the arc by changing the angle given to the `bend right` option.